# Raspberry Pi 3 recording sound noises

Tags: audio, raspbian, alsa, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to build a speech to text / speech recognition with my gaming headset (Creative Technology, Ltd Sound Blaster Tactic(3D) Sigma sound card). The usb soundcard is now working, however there's a white noise when i record a sound.

I've tested the mic in my windows machine and it works fine, but when i plug it in RPi 3 suddenly there's a noise. Not sure what's causing it, i've also tried distancing the Power cable and Net cable from the sound card but it's the same.

Can someone help me figure out what's causing it? Thanks in advance!

**To record:**

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord xtest.wav`

**To play**

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay xtest.wav`

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Fixed by adding `-f` option. `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -f cd xtest.wav`